# I have problem with provider : throw ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider

I have just started with state management, and my first try was with the Provider, I watched a tutorial on youtube and won't work on my code, so I copied and pasted and also wouldn't work .
so the idea is, there's a home screen
this home screen contains a list of people in ListTile, this ListTile has icon as trailing, you know to add and delete people from the favorite list screen that displays favorite people list
I don't know why, but here's my code :
this is the main.dart where the root is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note/Designs/Design_one.dart';
import 'package:note/Designs/Favorite_List.dart';
import 'package:note/Designs/another.dart';
import 'package:note/Screens/Random_Words.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Models/Favorite_List_Provider.dart';
import 'Screens/Hello_World.dart';
import 'Screens/Stateful_Widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) {
            favorite();
          },
        ),
      ],
     child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // Add the 5 lines from here...
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              shadowColor: Colors.blue,
              surfaceTintColor: Colors.orange,
              shape:
                  Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 4))),
        ),
        home: HomeScreen(),
        // DesignOne(
        //   Desc: '',
        //   Image: '',
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here's my provider when it extend a changeprovider :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class favorite extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _favoriteList = [];

  List<String> get favoriteList => _favoriteList;
 

  add(String name) {
    _favoriteList.add(name);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  remove(String name) {
    _favoriteList.removeWhere((element) => element == name);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

so this code supposed to be the home screen :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:note/Designs/Favorite_List.dart';
import 'package:note/Models/Favorite_List_Provider.dart';
import 'package:note/Models/Food_Models.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../Services/Fetch_Data.dart';
import 'Details_DesignOfDesignOne.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ListTile eachTile(favorite favorite, String name, String initials) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(name),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(initials),
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: (favorite.favoriteList.contains(name))
            ? Icon(Icons.check)
            : Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          if (favorite.favoriteList.contains(name)) {
            favorite.remove(name);
          } else {
            favorite.add(name);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Provider"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                "next",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => FavoriteScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Consumer<favorite>(
        builder: (context, favorite value, child) {
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              eachTile(value, "Elon Musk", "EM"),
              eachTile(value, "Kanye West", "KW"),
              eachTile(value, "Kim Kardashian", "KK"),
              eachTile(value, "Kobe Bryant", "KB"),
              eachTile(value, "Tom Hanks", "TH"),
              eachTile(value, "Lebron James", "LJ"),
              eachTile(value, "Michael Jordan", "MJ"),
              eachTile(value, "Joe Rogan", "JR"),
              eachTile(value, "Selena Gomez", "SG"),
              eachTile(value, "Oprah Winfrey", "OW"),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is supposed to display the list of favorite people that were token from home screen :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note/Models/Favorite_List_Provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class FavoriteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FavoriteScreen> createState() => _FavoriteScreenState();
}

class _FavoriteScreenState extends State<FavoriteScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Profile"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Consumer<favorite>(
          builder: (context, favorite value, child) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: value.favoriteList.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                      child: Text("Your Favorite List:"),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView(children: [
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(value.favoriteList[index - 1]),
                      ),
                    ]);
                  }
                });
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

and this is the Exception :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the instance from `create` on

```dart
providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) {
      return favorite(); //this one here
    },
  ),
],
```